# Parsing a website with "load more"/"show more" buttons

Tags: python, web-scraping, html-parsing

For my project, I need to get all the reviews for a business on Capterra(should work for different businesses). I'm not that experienced in web scraping so I have trouble trying to do that). I tried getting reviews for Hubspot(link to the reviews section: https://www.capterra.com/p/152373/HubSpot-CRM/reviews/)

I tried doing so using Python. (if there will be any js options, I'd be glad to hear those too)

Obviously, the basic bs4 HTML approach doesn't work and with Capterra I don't think that looking at its Fetch/XHR will help either(wasn't able to find anything related to pages there).

I feel kind of stuck at this point and don't really know how to approach this task. Recently stumbled across Playwright and Puppeteer but didn't really learn about them yet.

P.S: Methods mentioned above might be working and were simply not executed properly by me due to my incompetence in the field.

Comment: you might want to look more into selenium, it's exactly fitting your needs!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Ajax pagination API to load more reviews, e.g. (beware of captcha page though):

```py
import requests

api_url = "https://www.capterra.com/spotlight/rest/reviews"

params = {"apiVersion": "2", "productId": "152373", "from": "0", "size": "25"}
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0'}

with requests.session() as s:
    s.headers = headers

    n_pages = 2
    for params['from'] in range(0, 25*n_pages, 25):
        data = s.get(api_url, params=params).json()
        for h in data['hits']:
            print(f'{h["generalComments"][:30]:<30}   {h["prosText"][:30]:<30}   {h["consText"][:30]:<30}')
```

Prints:

```
                                 HubSpot is absolutely amazing!   I cannot think of any, to be h
It's great for making a sales    Hubspot manages our sales, mar   HubSpot's appointment calendar
I had to switch to different s   It has some interesting and us   As far as it is advertised as 
We are very satisfied with Hub   I love marketing, sales and cu   The onboarding of the HubSpot 
Easy to learn and easy to mana   It's so clean and intuitive, t   It's expensive. Although you'r
I really appreciate the user-f   HubSpot CRM is a powerful tool   it allows users to segment con
HubSpot is one of the most cri   The integration of everything    There is the occasional rough 
The CRM can easily be deployed   Hubspot is very scaleable and    The pricing model always keeps
Userfriendly, great tool to ha   I like the fact you can make c   I think the inbox feature was 
                                 I liked it for its ease of use   I did not like the waiting tim
We've made amazing sense of ou   I'm usually very leery about u   Sometimes the procedures for t
Bad things aside, I genuinely    It is an incredibly powerful C   I only have a few issues with 
Overall this is by far the bes   HubSpot is easy to deploy and    There are some features that a
As a small business, managing    HubSpot CRM is really great be   I have noticed that some featu
HubSpot has worked well for us   The biggest priorities for us    The biggest con for us is that
It has provided a central plac   I use the free version. It pro   _It is not intuitive to use. Y
Hubspot has a great starter pl   The email marketing tool is ve   The amount of emails you can s
Hubspot has been there every s   Hubspot has a ton of amazing f   Pricing per contact starts to 
Using Sequences has saved a hu   Keeping track of the customers   The full integration with cale
I recommend to anyone who make   Intuitive, easy to use, great    A few missing features, but Hu
absolutely perfect if goals ar   Hubspot is absolutely great as   Like almost every other CRM, H
Must-Try -  A Complete No Brai   > It is free and offers unlimi   I really can not say anything 
Once you get to know your way    It's easy to keep track of eve   It very rarely can be glitchy 
Overall, Hubspot is an incredi   I like the overall ease of use   Hubspot is a wonderful softwar
Overall, the ease of setup and   Without a doubt, the ability t   Some aspects of the software a
PlatformUser150 words about Th   HubSpot is a powerful and comp   While HubSpot offers many adva
I used to hate CRM software. I   The email campaigns, customer    The price you need to pay to p


...and so on.
```